# Selectively remove empty line after line change

Tags: tinymce, formatting, html-editor, wp-autop

In WP post editor, how can I change lines without adding an empty line?

I try to post this

```
One line
Second line
third line
```

But it always shows like this

```
One line

Second line

Third line
```

PS: I don't want to completely remove wpautop, because it will probably ruin all my previous posts.

Comment: Every time you type "enter" (the return character) the editor creates a new paragraph "<p>my content</p>" , the alternative is to type shift + enter so that the editor creates a line break instead "<br/>"

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to show the <br/> in the code?

Comment: Or alter the CSS that formats paragraphs...

Comment: If you want more information on what @gdaniel said, search for "soft return", that´s what it´s called.

Comment: @ixn I don't think you will be able to see the <br/> on the "View" tab, but maybe on the "Text" tab? If not, there might a plugin out there that does it. But that's the default behavior of the wp editor and many other editors out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gdaniel answered the bulk of question with this comment:

> Every time you type <kbd>Enter</kbd> (the return character) the editor
>   creates a new paragraph `<p>my content</p>`, the alternative is to
>   type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> so that the editor creates a
>   line break (`<br/>`) instead.

Note that the the `<br />` and `</p>` tags are added via `wpautop`, one of the display filters attached to the `wp_content` filter.

The`wp_content` filter is not applied to the content being viewed within the Text editor, so the `<br />` and `</p>` tags added by `wpautop` are not visible there. Instead, the raw text is displayed so the formatting is just a result of any newlines being present:

```
Soft return
Soft return
Soft return

Normal return

Normal return

Normal return
```

The Visual editor does not show  HTML tags, but the browser's developer tools can be used to inspect the Visual editor's HTML content, where the above would be rendered as:

```
<p>Soft return<br>
Soft return<br>
Soft return</p>
<p>Normal return</p>
<p>Normal return</p>
<p>Normal return</p>
```